# Prove that absolute convergence of sup norms implies uniform convergence of functions (Weierstrass M-test)

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $f_{n}$ be a sequence of bounded real-valued continuous functions on $X$ such that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|f_{n}\|$ is convergent. Then the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n}$ converges uniformly to some function $f$ on $X$, and that function $f$ is also continuous.

**MY ATTEMPT**

We want to prove that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a natural $N\geq 0$ such that for every $x\in X$ one has that
\begin{align*}
n\geq N \Rightarrow\left|\sum_{j=1}^{n}f_{j}(x) - f(x)\right| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

This is the same as proving that $\displaystyle s_{n} = \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{n}f_{j}(x)$ is Cauchy for every $x\in X$, since $\textbf{R}$ is complete.

Suppose that $\sum\|f_{n}\|$ converges. Then it is a Cauchy sequence. This means that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $N\geq 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
n\geq m \geq N \Rightarrow \sum_{j=m+1}^{n}\|f_{j}\| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

But we do also know that
\begin{align*}
\|f_{n}\| = \sup_{x\in X}|f_{n}(x)|
\end{align*}

Consequently, we have that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a natural number $N\geq 0$ such that for every $x\in X$
\begin{align*}
n\geq m \geq N \Rightarrow \left|\sum_{j=m+1}^{n}f_{j}(x)\right| \leq \sum_{j=m+1}^{n}|f_{j}(x)| \leq \sum_{j=m+1}^{n}\|f_{j}\| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}

whence we conclude that $s_{n}$ is Cauchy for every $x\in X$, and we are done.

**My concerns**

I am new to this and I am a little bit unsure about the Cauchy condition part.

Could someone tell me if I am proving it correctly?

Comment: Yes, it seems fine to me. About which step (inequality) are unsure in particular?

Comment: The first one where I state that we should prove that $s_n$ is Cauchy.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the point there is can we can even show (as you did) the sequence $s_n$ is Cauchy uniformly in $x \in X$ in the sense that $N$ for the "Cauchyness" does not depend on $x$. This should then allow us to show that the series is in fact non only pointwise but even uniformly convergent.